# How do I access network file share?

Tags: 12.04, networking, samba

Ubuntu/Linux NU-B here.  I have a physical ubuntu server sharing a folder and is accessible via windows GUI.

I installed another Ubuntu Server under VMWorkstation as a Virtual machine and is on the network and can go to internet and can ping the local network as well.  I need to access the shared folder which is in the physical ubuntu server  from my virtual ubuntu server via cmd line.... any help is appreciated.

Comment: didn't this question mention FTP previously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer to be in one of the post

//server/share /mnt/mountname cifs username=server_user,password=user_password,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=07‌​77 0 0

Answer (score 2):

There is a command called smbclient which is a bit like a command line ftp client for the smb/cifs protocol.

To use it, just turn those windows backslashes into forward slashes.

```
$ smbclient //server/share
```

It will use your current user as username and it will ask you for your password. You can change the username with the -U option

```
$ smbclient -U jrwren2 //server/share
```

Comment: Hi Jay thank you for your response. when I use the cmd I get NT Status log on Failure.... & it does not connect.

Comment: log on failure is exactly what it sounds like. You must be using the incorrect username/password.